# Выбор из базы данных SQL определённых значений

Tags: sql, sql-server

В БД существует таблица, где в одной из колонок есть номера аудиторий. В поле может  быть указана либо одна аудитория, либо несколько. Мне нужно составить запрос, который выбирает записи, в которых указана только одна аудитория. 
Пытался сделать разными способами, но не выходило. Имя таблицы Загрузка, колонки - Аудитории.

Comment: Покажите, что у вас уже готово, чтобы люди могли исправить ваш запрос.

Comment: @АмирЗакиров я пробовал:Select Аудитории From Загрузка where Аудитории like '%,%' или же where Аудитории like '%[^,]'

Comment: Так же вы не указали, с какой БД работаете.

Comment: *В поле может быть указана либо одна аудитория, либо несколько.* Покажите примеры такого содержимого поля. И укажите точную СУБД.

Comment: @Akina СУБД MS SQL Management Studio, Пример:   
1317 или
2251,2252 или
7108б,1117,1407

Comment: Management Studio - это не СУБД. Это утилита для работы с СУБД Sql Server.

Comment: Тогда тупо `WHERE CHARINDEX(',', field) = 0` или `> 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Аудитории from Загрузка
where Аудитории in (select distinct LTRIM(value) FROM Загрузка CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Аудитории, ','))
```

Запрос писал на MS Sql Server. Так же я считал, что номера аудитории записаны через запятую. Если нет, необходимо поменять символ, по которому происходит разделение строки.

Comment: MS SQL Management Studio пишет: Недопустимое имя объекта "STRING_SPLIT".

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205829/sql-server-2016-invalid-object-name-string-split)

Comment: @ViktorBezrukov - функция [STRING_SPLIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) появилась в Sql Server 2016. Если у вас более низкая версия, посмотрите варианты [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10914576/5045688). Или [здесь](http://blogs.rsdn.ru/sql/6380659) (код не открывается по нажатию на плюсик, но в сорсах html он есть)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Sql Server стоит 2017-го года

Comment: @ViktorBezrukov это у вас managment studio небось 17го года а не сервер. или база в режиме совместимости старом

Comment: @teran скорее БД, т.к. сервер тоже 17-го

Comment: @ViktorBezrukov вы уровни совместимости смотрели? Я оставлял ссылку выше.